# .rdl and .rdl.data files

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 with Advanced Services. I have a visual studio solution that has files with extension .rdl and .rdl.data. How can I open and modify these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDL is the Report Definition Language - e.g. the definition files for the [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510782.aspx).

You should be able to use those either from the Reporting Services web dashboard, or you can check out the [standalone Report Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157166.aspx) to open and modify those files.